# ES6: Is there a way to import and assign in one statement?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I have a lot of small JS snippets that I need to call in various places throughout my application.  The code is in multiple files, and main.js imports it as modules and assigns it to a global variable, as in the following example:

```
import shared from './shared.js';
window.shared = shared;
```

Is there a way to combine the import and assignment in to one statement?  I have quite a few files to handle, and it's going to get repetitive.

Comment: Populating the window scope with lots of little functions kind of defeats the purpose of modules. Have you considered assigning to a single library on `window` instead, or just importing a helper library everywhere it's needed?

Comment: Hmmm... so that would be similar to what I have, except that all functions would be in the shared.js file?  That's what I was doing, but it got confusing, and the namespaces got too long...

Comment: It should be quite simple. For example: `import { helperFn1 } from './helpers;'`

Comment: Hmmm... This would mean I have more import statements in my pages.  Webpack is currently placing them in a single file, which is included by the global layout.

Comment: Yes. Importing dependencies explicitly for each module they're needed in is far more maintainable than using something that has magically been assigned to the global scope.